# Manually Upload Files from Android

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I can't find a way of uploading non-media or photo files from my android 2.2 phone to my U1 cloud. When I select "upload file" the choose a file option only allows media or photos. Is there a way around this as I would really like to be able to sync (manually upload) modified files from my phone?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to upload any file type from your phone via the Ubuntu One Android app though at the current stage in its development to do this you will also need to install a file manager app. Most of the available file managers in the Android Market (or Play Store as it likes to be known now!) will work. A couple of free examples are [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm&feature=search_result), and [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&feature=search_result)

After you have installed a file manager launch the Ubuntu One application and press the add button and select the "Add File" option.

[image]

You'll get a option box pop-up, from this select the file manager that you have installed and then navigate to the file you wish to upload and select it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it via the Ubuntu One app as far as a I know but you can move the file into your u1 directory using the "Files" application.

Anything in there gets synced to the cloud and will be found in your "Ubuntu One" folder.

Comment: I edited a file in the u1 folder. I have clicked on the synchronize button, but the file was not synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

[The other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/102585/78161) does work - but it involves transferring one file at a time! There is no way to upload batches of files or a folder. Ubuntu One should fix this - and also enable the uploading of a folder to Ubuntu One, just as can be done from a PC.

A simple solution is to go to Google Play and download the **WiFi File Transfer** app. This will then enable you to look into your Nexus from your PC and transfer files from it or to it, without having to connect it via USB. It will download the group of files as a `.zip` archive or as separate files.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a tutorial of how to use the WiFi File Transfer app, if applicable. If you are able to - please include it. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and great answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any file browser (even the standard one) to upload your files.

Just select the files you want with the file browser and select the share icon. In the menu that pops up you should be able to select Ubuntu one. Then choose the u1 folder where you want to upload and you're done.